# Exercise of continuity of a function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I apply the definition of continuity to the following exercise to find the points where $f$ is continuous?

$$f\left ( x,y \right )=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x^{2}+y^{2}, \textrm{if}\,\,   x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4\\ 
1\: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: , \textrm{if}\,\,   x^{2}+y^{2}>  4
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Here is a useful document on continuity in multiple dimensions:

Comment: http://www.math.ucdenver.edu/~esulliva/Calculus3/LimitLaws.pdf